# How to fix 'Git tag already exists' but that tag did not exists?

Tags: git, build, azure-devops, devops

My setup: git-repository on an Azure DevOps.

[image]

When i create a git tag using Git Repo Tagger (Task on pipeline) like "12.0.0101" The tagger returns

```
 ##[error]Command failed: git tag  -a "12.0.0101" -m "12.0.0101" 
 fatal: tag '12.0.0101' already exists
 [error]Git Repo Tagger Failed.
```

But when i list all the tags with

```
git tag -l or git tag
```

That tag did not exists

I just tried to checkout that not existant tag, but as expected, the tag not exists.

If i try to generate manually that tag, (from the azure devops page) it works, but in the build pipeline, fails.

Also, i have many builds with the same task, and it works, only in this branch seems not working.

Comment: Drop the `-l` to list all tags. Otherwise you’re trying to filter the list tags without passing a filter.

Comment: Didn't work @evolutionxbox

Comment: What didn’t work? If git says the tag exists, it does.

Comment: As a guess, I'd bet you have something that is making your CI script run the `git tag -a` command twice.

Comment: Nope @torek, but... I'm thinking that someone has a pending checkin on the server agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its solved changed this configuration, seems like in any moment, the git tag only exists in the server.

[image]

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Marked!